# Strange issue where we are facing infinite loading for a few customer when we edit them in backend in magento2

Tags: magento2

Can you please help us to solve a issue in magento2.3.x where when we edit a few customers in backend everything stuck in a loop and server goes down.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

Run command line:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
>
> bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush